# Ontologies: DataProperty range vs. subClassOf "range"

Tags: xsd, ontology

assuming we have the following:

```
...
Declaration(DataProperty(:postal-code))
DataPropertyRange(:postal-code xsd:string)
SubClassOf(:Address DataExactCardinality(1 :postal-code xsd:string))
```

why do I need to specify xsd:string in the last line? Why does it not look like this:

```
SubClassOf(:Address DataExactCardinality(1 :postal-code))
```

We already now, that postal-code should be xsd:string. Or the other way around: Why should I use DataProperties? Why don't we have:

```
SubClassOf(:Address DataExactCardinality( 1: "postal-code" xsd:string ))
// note the quotes
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the xsd:string is unnecessary - it could be useful if the range axiom became separated from the ontology.

In the second case, dropping the range would change the ontology in a different way: the range you're specifying is only valid for Address and other subclasses of that expression. Any other use of the property would not include the range definition, and theoretically the property could be used with a different range. This would be unusual, although not wrong.